Completely replace master branch with migration branch
I have a master branch and a migration branch. We completely changed the codebase in the migration branch, and now we want to replace the master branch with the migration branch. Is there a proper way to do this?
I think merging is not an option, as I want to replace Master. 
Also, the master branch is a protected branch, so I can't directly force push in the master.
I tried merging, but I am getting lots of conflicts, which I don't want to have as it is a replacement, not a merge. 
Is there any proper way to deal with this situation?

You could first merge master into a branch started from migration forcing git to not bring over any changes from master (so keeping stuff as it is in migration) and then create a PR into master which then will leave the commit tree just like it is in migration so you get the desired result:
git fetch origin
git checkout -b recipe origin/migration
git merge -s ours origin/master # we merge master _but_ we discard any changes coming from that branch

Now, you can create a PR using the branch and once you merge it into master, the branch will have the content of migration..... just make sure you do a real merge and not a rebase or squash merge... that is so that, in history, the 2 branches look related.

You can merge the two branches with the merge strategy ours (-s), not to be confused with the merge option ours (-X). The ours merge strategy favors the history of the current branch, discarding everything that happened on the other branch.
In your case, since you want to maintain the history on the migration branch and you cannot push directly to master, you need to rely on two temporary branches: one which is simply a copy of master, and a second one with the merge between master's copy and migration.
# creating a copy of master for a later PR into master
git branch master_copy master

# checking out migration
#git checkout migration

# creating a temporary branch from migration and switching to it
git checkout -b migration_temp

# merging master_copy into migration_temp and keeping the history from migration_temp
git merge -s ours master_copy

# switching to branch master_copy
git checkout master_copy

# fast-forward merge as every commit in master_copy is already 
# contained in migration_temp while keeping migration_temp's worktree
git merge migration_temp

# pushing master_copy to the remote
git push

# deleting the temporary branch migration_temp
git branch -d migration_temp

The previous git merge -s ours was necessary to "trick" Git into thinking that master_copy's history, and therefore master's history, is part of migration_temp (and it is, as now its commits are reachable from migration_temp), while in reality we've kept migration's worktree.
Now, since master_copy was fast-forwarded to migration's HEAD commit, you can create a PR from master_copy to master that will be resolved with a fast-forward as well, since every commit in master is already contained in master_copy.
PS @eftshift0's answer is definitely more concise than my solution. He posted his while I was editing mine.
